# popen only returns partial output

Tags: php, linux

I am using `popen` to execute a command and the problem is that I only get output immediately at the start (entries go in my database) when the script executes, and after it is finished which makes no sense to me. I am trying to get it so that input is constantly going into my database along the way when the `popen` process is working. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$handle = popen ('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/cave.wmv ' .
    '-deinterlace -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 ' .
    '-s 480x320 -f flv /home/g/Desktop/file.flv 2>&1', 'r');
if ($handle) {
    echo 'after handle if <br>';
    while(! feof ($handle)) {
        echo 'after handle while <br>';
        echo $read = fgets ($handle);
        echo 'after read <br>';
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO video (timestamp, vid_id, file_name, ' .
            'uploader, title, subject_id, status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
        $stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql);
        echo 'after stmt3 <br>';
        $result = $stmt3->execute(array('','',$read,'','untitled','',0))
            or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
        print "after execute " . $result . "<br>";
        if (!$result) {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
        }
    } 
    pclose ($handle);
}
```

**Output is:**

```
    after handle if
    after handle while
    ffmpeg version git-N-30561-g6700aa8, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    built on Jun 5 2011 21:10:26 with gcc 4.5.2 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    libavutil 51. 4. 0 / 51. 4. 0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    libavcodec 53. 6. 1 / 53. 6. 1 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    libavformat 53. 2. 0 / 53. 2. 0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    libavdevice 53. 1. 1 / 53. 1. 1 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    libavfilter 2. 13. 0 / 2. 13. 0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    libswscale 0. 14. 1 / 0. 14. 1 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001) after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Input #0, asf, from '/home/geoff/Desktop/cave.wmv': after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Metadata: after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    WMFSDKVersion : 11.0.5721.5145 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    WMFSDKNeeded : 0.0.0.0000 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    IsVBR : 0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Duration: 00:01:37.93, bitrate: 263 kb/s after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: vc1 (Advanced), yuv420p, 320x240, 256 kb/s, PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [buffer @ 0xa16c200] w:320 h:240 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param: after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [scale @ 0xa17a120] w:320 h:240 fmt:yuv420p -> w:480 h:320 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] Default settings detected, using medium profile after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] using SAR=1/1 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle Cache64 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] profile High, level 2.1 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] 264 - core 115 r1995 c1e60b9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=1 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Output #0, flv, to '/home/geoff/Desktop/file.flv': after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Metadata: after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    WMFSDKVersion : 11.0.5721.5145 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    WMFSDKNeeded : 0.0.0.0000 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    IsVBR : 0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    encoder : Lavf53.2.0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 480x320 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Stream mapping: after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
 //////////// NOT ENTERED//////////  frame= 53 fps= 0 q=29.0 size= 22kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate= 481.4kbits/s frame= 69 fps= 68 q=29.0 size= 47kB time=00:00:00.90 bitrate= 424.4kbits/s frame= 87 fps= 57 q=29.0 size= 70kB time=00:00:01.50 bitrate= 380.1kbits/s frame= 107 fps= 52 q=29.0 size= 94kB time=00:00:02.16 bitrate= 356.1kbits/s frame= 126 fps= 50 q=29.0 size= 113kB time=00:00:02.80 bitrate= 329.9kbits/s frame= 148 fps= 49 q=29.0 size= 133kB time=00:00:03.53 bitrate= 307.5kbits/s frame= 166 fps= 47 q=29.0 size= 150kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate= 297.9kbits/s frame= 181 fps= 45 q=29.0 size= 167kB time=00:00:04.63 bitrate= 295.7kbits/s frame= 197 fps= 43 q=29.0 size= 192kB time=00:00:05.17 bitrate= 303.5kbits/s frame= 215 fps= 42 q=29.0 size= 219kB time=00:00:05.77 bitrate= 310.7kbits/s frame= 236 fps= 42 q=29.0 size= 242kB time=00:00:06.47 bitrate= 306.0kbits/s frame= 256 fps= 42 q=29.0 size= 268kB time=00:00:07.14 bitrate= 307.7kbits/s frame= 278 fps= 42 q=29.0 size= 293kB time=00:00:07.87 bitrate= 305.1kbits/s frame= 303 fps= 42 q=29.0 size= 323kB time=00:00:08.70 bitrate= 304.2kbits/s frame= 327 fps= 43 q=29.0 size= 343kB time=00:00:09.50 bitrate= 295.9kbits/s frame= 345 fps= 42 q=29.0 size= 370kB time=00:00:10.11 bitrate= 300.0kbits/s frame= 364 fps= 42 q=29.0 size= 392kB time=00:00:10.74 bitrate= 298.9kbits/s frame= 382 fps= 41 q=29.0 size= 414kB time=00:00:11.34 bitrate= 298.8kbits/s frame= 397 fps= 41 q=29.0 size= 440kB time=00:00:11.84 bitrate= 304.2kbits/s frame= 415 fps= 41 q=29.0 size= 463kB time=00:00:12.44 bitrate= 304.9kbits/s frame= 432 fps= 40 q=29.0 size= 489kB time=00:00:13.01 bitrate= 307.7kbits/s frame= 451 fps= 40 q=29.0 size= 513kB time=00:00:13.64 bitrate= 307.9kbits/s frame= 471 fps= 40 q=29.0 size= 534kB time=00:00:14.31 bitrate= 305.7kbits/s frame= 492 fps= 40 q=29.0 size= 556kB time=00:00:15.01 bitrate= 303.4kbits/s frame= 510 fps= 40 q=29.0 size= 596kB time=00:00:15.61 bitrate= 312.8kbits/s frame= 528 fps= 40 q=29.0 size= 620kB time=00:00:16.21 bitrate= 313.3kbits/s frame= 548 fps= 40 q=29.0 size= 644kB time=00:00:16.88 bitrate= 312.5kbits/s frame= 565 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 680kB time=00:00:17.45 bitrate= 319.3kbits/s frame= 583 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 713kB time=00:00:18.05 bitrate= 323.4kbits/s frame= 601 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 743kB time=00:00:18.65 bitrate= 326.3kbits/s frame= 618 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 770kB time=00:00:19.22 bitrate= 328.1kbits/s frame= 637 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 795kB time=00:00:19.85 bitrate= 328.0kbits/s frame= 655 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 823kB time=00:00:20.45 bitrate= 329.8kbits/s frame= 676 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 850kB time=00:00:21.15 bitrate= 329.0kbits/s frame= 694 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 877kB time=00:00:21.75 bitrate= 330.1kbits/s frame= 712 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 904kB time=00:00:22.35 bitrate= 331.1kbits/s frame= 728 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 934kB time=00:00:22.88 bitrate= 334.1kbits/s frame= 746 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 961kB time=00:00:23.49 bitrate= 335.0kbits/s frame= 762 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 999kB time=00:00:24.02 bitrate= 340.6kbits/s frame= 779 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 1019kB time=00:00:24.59 bitrate= 339.3kbits/s frame= 797 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 1042kB time=00:00:25.19 bitrate= 338.7kbits/s frame= 811 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 1060kB time=00:00:25.65 bitrate= 338.3kbits/s frame= 829 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 1086kB time=00:00:26.25 bitrate= 338.8kbits/s frame= 846 fps= 37 q=29.0 size= 1112kB time=00:00:26.82 bitrate= 339.6kbits/s frame= 857 fps= 37 q=29.0 size= 1130kB time=00:00:27.19 bitrate= 340.5kbits/s frame= 874 fps= 37 q=29.0 size= 1156kB time=00:00:27.76 bitrate= 341.2kbits/s frame= 890 fps= 37 q=29.0 size= 1177kB time=00:00:28.29 bitrate= 340.8kbits/s frame= 901 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1196kB time=00:00:28.66 bitrate= 341.9kbits/s frame= 912 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1215kB time=00:00:29.02 bitrate= 342.9kbits/s frame= 927 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1236kB time=00:00:29.52 bitrate= 342.8kbits/s frame= 941 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1268kB time=00:00:29.99 bitrate= 346.4kbits/s frame= 953 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1299kB time=00:00:30.39 bitrate= 350.1kbits/s frame= 965 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1327kB time=00:00:30.79 bitrate= 353.0kbits/s frame= 976 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1348kB time=00:00:31.16 bitrate= 354.4kbits/s frame= 985 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1366kB time=00:00:31.46 bitrate= 355.8kbits/s frame= 994 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1385kB time=00:00:31.76 bitrate= 357.1kbits/s frame= 1010 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1427kB time=00:00:32.29 bitrate= 362.0kbits/s frame= 1026 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1455kB time=00:00:32.83 bitrate= 363.1kbits/s frame= 1039 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1482kB time=00:00:33.26 bitrate= 365.0kbits/s frame= 1048 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1502kB time=00:00:33.56 bitrate= 366.6kbits/s frame= 1062 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1526kB time=00:00:34.03 bitrate= 367.3kbits/s frame= 1078 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1549kB time=00:00:34.56 bitrate= 367.2kbits/s frame= 1092 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 1574kB time=00:00:35.03 bitrate= 368.0kbits/s frame= 1103 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1585kB time=00:00:35.40 bitrate= 366.7kbits/s frame= 1120 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1603kB time=00:00:35.97 bitrate= 365.0kbits/s frame= 1136 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1630kB time=00:00:36.50 bitrate= 365.7kbits/s frame= 1144 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1646kB time=00:00:36.77 bitrate= 366.7kbits/s frame= 1155 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1665kB time=00:00:37.13 bitrate= 367.2kbits/s frame= 1168 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1688kB time=00:00:37.57 bitrate= 368.1kbits/s frame= 1179 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1705kB time=00:00:37.93 bitrate= 368.2kbits/s frame= 1195 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 1731kB time=00:00:38.47 bitrate= 368.7kbits/s frame= 1208 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1751kB time=00:00:38.90 bitrate= 368.6kbits/s frame= 1225 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1776kB time=00:00:39.47 bitrate= 368.6kbits/s frame= 1234 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1788kB time=00:00:39.77 bitrate= 368.2kbits/s frame= 1243 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1809kB time=00:00:40.07 bitrate= 369.7kbits/s frame= 1256 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1835kB time=00:00:40.50 bitrate= 371.1kbits/s frame= 1274 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1849kB time=00:00:41.10 bitrate= 368.4kbits/s frame= 1294 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1867kB time=00:00:41.77 bitrate= 366.1kbits/s frame= 1313 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1891kB time=00:00:42.40 bitrate= 365.3kbits/s frame= 1326 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1913kB time=00:00:42.84 bitrate= 365.8kbits/s frame= 1341 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1943kB time=00:00:43.34 bitrate= 367.2kbits/s frame= 1353 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1966kB time=00:00:43.74 bitrate= 368.2kbits/s frame= 1368 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 1992kB time=00:00:44.24 bitrate= 368.8kbits/s frame= 1386 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2021kB time=00:00:44.84 bitrate= 369.1kbits/s frame= 1403 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2050kB time=00:00:45.41 bitrate= 369.8kbits/s frame= 1419 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2075kB time=00:00:45.94 bitrate= 370.0kbits/s frame= 1435 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2097kB time=00:00:46.47 bitrate= 369.7kbits/s frame= 1451 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2118kB time=00:00:47.01 bitrate= 369.0kbits/s frame= 1470 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2142kB time=00:00:47.64 bitrate= 368.3kbits/s frame= 1483 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2161kB time=00:00:48.08 bitrate= 368.2kbits/s frame= 1499 fps= 32 q=26.0 size= 2201kB time=00:00:48.61 bitrate= 370.8kbits/s frame= 1508 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 2218kB time=00:00:48.91 bitrate= 371.5kbits/s frame= 1515 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2232kB time=00:00:49.14 bitrate= 372.0kbits/s frame= 1532 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2265kB time=00:00:49.71 bitrate= 373.2kbits/s frame= 1547 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2295kB time=00:00:50.21 bitrate= 374.4kbits/s frame= 1562 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2321kB time=00:00:50.71 bitrate= 374.8kbits/s frame= 1575 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2343kB time=00:00:51.15 bitrate= 375.2kbits/s frame= 1585 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2359kB time=00:00:51.48 bitrate= 375.3kbits/s frame= 1600 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2382kB time=00:00:51.98 bitrate= 375.3kbits/s frame= 1609 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2396kB time=00:00:52.28 bitrate= 375.5kbits/s frame= 1620 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2420kB time=00:00:52.65 bitrate= 376.5kbits/s frame= 1636 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2446kB time=00:00:53.18 bitrate= 376.7kbits/s frame= 1654 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2474kB time=00:00:53.78 bitrate= 376.8kbits/s frame= 1670 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2501kB time=00:00:54.32 bitrate= 377.2kbits/s frame= 1689 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2531kB time=00:00:54.95 bitrate= 377.3kbits/s frame= 1705 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2566kB time=00:00:55.48 bitrate= 378.9kbits/s frame= 1723 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2597kB time=00:00:56.09 bitrate= 379.2kbits/s frame= 1741 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2628kB time=00:00:56.69 bitrate= 379.8kbits/s frame= 1757 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2670kB time=00:00:57.22 bitrate= 382.2kbits/s frame= 1772 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2694kB time=00:00:57.72 bitrate= 382.4kbits/s frame= 1787 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2714kB time=00:00:58.22 bitrate= 381.8kbits/s frame= 1802 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2738kB time=00:00:58.72 bitrate= 382.0kbits/s frame= 1818 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2761kB time=00:00:59.26 bitrate= 381.7kbits/s frame= 1833 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2781kB time=00:00:59.75 bitrate= 381.2kbits/s frame= 1848 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2805kB time=00:01:00.26 bitrate= 381.3kbits/s frame= 1865 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2835kB time=00:01:00.82 bitrate= 381.7kbits/s frame= 1879 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2856kB time=00:01:01.29 bitrate= 381.7kbits/s frame= 1895 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2874kB time=00:01:01.82 bitrate= 380.8kbits/s frame= 1910 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2895kB time=00:01:02.32 bitrate= 380.4kbits/s frame= 1930 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2920kB time=00:01:02.99 bitrate= 379.7kbits/s frame= 1953 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2946kB time=00:01:03.76 bitrate= 378.4kbits/s frame= 1974 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 2971kB time=00:01:04.46 bitrate= 377.5kbits/s frame= 1991 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3005kB time=00:01:05.03 bitrate= 378.5kbits/s frame= 2010 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3050kB time=00:01:05.66 bitrate= 380.5kbits/s frame= 2029 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3079kB time=00:01:06.29 bitrate= 380.5kbits/s frame= 2049 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3107kB time=00:01:06.96 bitrate= 380.1kbits/s frame= 2067 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3136kB time=00:01:07.56 bitrate= 380.2kbits/s frame= 2087 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3162kB time=00:01:08.23 bitrate= 379.6kbits/s frame= 2105 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3183kB time=00:01:08.83 bitrate= 378.8kbits/s frame= 2126 fps= 31 q=29.0 size= 3209kB time=00:01:09.53 bitrate= 378.0kbits/s frame= 2144 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3243kB time=00:01:10.13 bitrate= 378.7kbits/s frame= 2165 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3267kB time=00:01:10.83 bitrate= 377.8kbits/s frame= 2182 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3293kB time=00:01:11.40 bitrate= 377.8kbits/s frame= 2200 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3320kB time=00:01:12.00 bitrate= 377.7kbits/s frame= 2219 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3352kB time=00:01:12.64 bitrate= 378.0kbits/s frame= 2239 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3383kB time=00:01:13.30 bitrate= 378.1kbits/s frame= 2259 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3425kB time=00:01:13.97 bitrate= 379.3kbits/s frame= 2278 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3455kB time=00:01:14.60 bitrate= 379.4kbits/s frame= 2298 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3491kB time=00:01:15.27 bitrate= 379.9kbits/s frame= 2317 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3514kB time=00:01:15.91 bitrate= 379.2kbits/s frame= 2340 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3539kB time=00:01:16.67 bitrate= 378.1kbits/s frame= 2358 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3562kB time=00:01:17.27 bitrate= 377.6kbits/s frame= 2380 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3590kB time=00:01:18.01 bitrate= 377.0kbits/s frame= 2402 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3617kB time=00:01:18.74 bitrate= 376.3kbits/s frame= 2426 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3639kB time=00:01:19.54 bitrate= 374.8kbits/s frame= 2447 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3662kB time=00:01:20.24 bitrate= 373.8kbits/s frame= 2467 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3691kB time=00:01:20.91 bitrate= 373.6kbits/s frame= 2486 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3721kB time=00:01:21.54 bitrate= 373.8kbits/s frame= 2506 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3764kB time=00:01:22.21 bitrate= 375.0kbits/s frame= 2523 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3789kB time=00:01:22.78 bitrate= 374.9kbits/s frame= 2541 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3824kB time=00:01:23.38 bitrate= 375.7kbits/s frame= 2557 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3855kB time=00:01:23.91 bitrate= 376.3kbits/s frame= 2574 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3893kB time=00:01:24.48 bitrate= 377.5kbits/s frame= 2590 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3928kB time=00:01:25.01 bitrate= 378.5kbits/s frame= 2608 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3963kB time=00:01:25.61 bitrate= 379.2kbits/s frame= 2627 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 3992kB time=00:01:26.25 bitrate= 379.1kbits/s frame= 2648 fps= 32 q=29.0 size= 4023kB time=00:01:26.95 bitrate= 379.0kbits/s frame= 2670 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4051kB time=00:01:27.68 bitrate= 378.4kbits/s frame= 2694 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4077kB time=00:01:28.48 bitrate= 377.4kbits/s frame= 2712 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4106kB time=00:01:29.08 bitrate= 377.6kbits/s frame= 2729 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4142kB time=00:01:29.65 bitrate= 378.5kbits/s frame= 2743 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4175kB time=00:01:30.12 bitrate= 379.5kbits/s frame= 2763 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4215kB time=00:01:30.79 bitrate= 380.3kbits/s frame= 2780 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4247kB time=00:01:31.35 bitrate= 380.8kbits/s frame= 2799 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4278kB time=00:01:31.99 bitrate= 380.9kbits/s frame= 2818 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4307kB time=00:01:32.62 bitrate= 380.9kbits/s frame= 2839 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4328kB time=00:01:33.32 bitrate= 379.9kbits/s frame= 2858 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4354kB time=00:01:33.96 bitrate= 379.6kbits/s frame= 2875 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4384kB time=00:01:34.52 bitrate= 379.9kbits/s frame= 2895 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4413kB time=00:01:35.19 bitrate= 379.8kbits/s frame= 2912 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4436kB time=00:01:35.76 bitrate= 379.5kbits/s frame= 2933 fps= 33 q=29.0 size= 4463kB time=00:01:36.46 bitrate= 379.0kbits/s frame= 2934 fps= 33 q=29.0 Lsize= 4512kB time=00:01:37.86 bitrate= 377.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 after read
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    video:4454kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.293893% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    frame I:13 Avg QP:19.66 size: 13557 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] frame P:1221 Avg QP:23.87 size: 2962 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] frame B:1700 Avg QP:30.26 size: 451 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] consecutive B-frames: 7.2% 33.5% 39.7% 19.6% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] mb I I16..4: 9.6% 73.3% 17.0% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] mb P I16..4: 0.4% 2.5% 0.4% P16..4: 37.8% 18.9% 8.1% 0.0% 0.0% skip:31.8% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] mb B I16..4: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0% B16..8: 30.9% 1.9% 0.4% direct: 0.9% skip:65.8% L0:30.8% L1:63.8% BI: 5.4% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] 8x8 transform intra:74.5% inter:72.0% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 79.7% 84.7% 50.5% inter: 14.2% 13.9% 0.7% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 60% 18% 4% 18% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 12% 10% 4% 10% 15% 7% 10% 7% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 19% 9% 4% 10% 13% 6% 8% 4% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 21% 22% 12% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.8% UV:0.4% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] ref P L0: 65.4% 20.8% 10.8% 2.9% 0.0% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] ref B L0: 91.4% 8.0% 0.6% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] ref B L1: 95.6% 4.4% after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    [libx264 @ 0xa1797e0] kb/s:372.66 after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
    after handle while
    after read
    after stmt3
    after execute 1
```

Comment: Could ffmpeg be writing to some other output stream than stderr?

Comment: ...why are you putting video files into a database? like that?

Comment: I am not man, I am trying to capture the output of the conversion and put in database! This is a test script just so I can see if output is constantly going in.

Comment: @Marc how could I know if it was? If I just echo $read, all output is displayed at end of process.

Comment: @Scarface: run the command on the command line, and redirect stderr to a file instead of stdout `2> stderr.txt` and see if the output still shows up or goes into the file.

Comment: When I do your suggestion, all the output goes into the text file and constantly updates like I would expect. If only I could get that behavior through a php script.

Comment: And nothing into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you perhaps have a unique constraint (such as a primary key) on the `timestamp` column? Since the PHP `time()` function gives you the UNIX time value (with a one-second resolution), you won't be allowed to insert records in quick succession - they will have the same key.

The reason I posit that is because you're neither checking the return value from `execute` to detect a failure nor calling `errorInfo` in the case of that failure.

Even if that unique constraint *isn't* a problem, you should be checking return values and the error information. That should tell you *exactly* what the problem is.

Another thing to try is to temporarily put debugging `print` statements after *every* line to track the flow through your code.

Comment: Your suggestion is very innovative and pretty genius. I got excited when I saw it because I thought it might be it! I guess I can only expect from someone with 149k, but it unfortunately did not lead me to a solution yet. See my edit. timestamp is just a int(11) and the page is blank after the code is executed so I guess there were no errors?

Comment: @Scarface, I think `if (!$stmt3) {` in your updated code should be `if (!$result) {` - that may be why you're not seeing the error.

Comment: I changed it and got same result. Could it be an issue with php.ini? Why is it that output is only coming at start in end? Is it most likely the database or insert statement?

Comment: @Scarface, put a `print`-type statement after _every_ line in that snippet and see where it's stopping (if indeed it _is_ stopping). The segment is not so large as to make that onerous and it will hopefully pinpoint the exact statement causing a problem.

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question, I have been struggling with this for a while so my brain is dying but what exactly do you mean? The output stops in the database at 'Press [q] to stop, [?] for help' (last amount of ouput in initially) and then some final input at the end of the process is inserted. By putting print '-type'; I just get a bunch of print types after the process is finished.

Comment: @Scarface, sorry, that's my fault, I should have been more explicit. I didn't mean `print '-type'`, I meant some type of print statement. For example. `print 'after prepare<br>'` after the prepare line, `print 'after execute ' . $result . '<br>'` after the execute line and so on. Check the syntax of those though, I'm not sure. The intent is to give you relevant information after every executed line.

Comment: You mean to find when the output stops? It stops right after the conversion starts. So if it was a command terminal, the command goes in, then it shows some info and the press q to stop. That is all in my database. The it starts converting and everything in between is lost. Then at the end it enters the summary/final output into the database. When I tried your echoing I got 'after prepare
after execute 1' echoed the number of times there are entries in the database.

Comment: @Sacrface: after _every_ line, and _every_ piece of information, that means `handle`, `read`, `sql`, `stmt3` and `result`. Then examine that output and post it in an update to your question if possible.

Comment: The formatting is poor, I hope you can read it pax. You can see, the output after [q] to quit is what I am looking for (echoed by fread). That part does not go in database and is echoed after finished and then at the end the last portion is inserted into the database.

Comment: @Scarface, can you mark (eg, with an `*` at the start of the line) _which_ lines are being put in the DB? Your executes are working fine based on the output.

Comment: Everything is entered before and after the line I highlighted ///not entered. See my update.

Comment: I should probably add that everything before the line I marked is entered instantly in several database entries. Same with everything after. I assume because they are information instantly provided by command line. The line I marked is information on progress and should actively update in the command line as the process works.

Comment: @Scarface: Ah, so everything _is_ entered, it's just a matter of _when._ If that's the case, it may just be buffering.

Comment: NONONO. The line I marked is NOT entered. That is the problem. Everything before that line and after is entered at the beginning and end of the process. The progress of the process in between which is that line that I marked with //////Not Entered, is not entered. That has been the whole problem! I have no idea why everything on that line is lost and I am going crazy!

Comment: @Scarface: then you have moved beyond my area of expertise. There are a few more possibilities you can look into, properties of that line that others don't have. 1/ It's long. Damn long. Over 13K. 2/ It's the first line after what looks like an input operation (press q to quit ...). 3/ It looks like those line sequences that have carriage returns without newlines (so that it doesn't scroll the screen but instead keeps overwriting a single status line). That's where I'd be looking based on past experience. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: You have been a pretty big help so far pax, I appreciate it. The data actually does go in the database. It was too long before so I used preg_match to shorten and test, but it comes in all at once. The initial data up to press q to quit comes in right away, the process runs, and then all the information past that point comes into the database at the end after the process. I don't know where that output is going. If I use 2> stderr.txt at the end and funnel it to a text doc, the information constantly comes in along the way. Could output be going somewhere else?

Comment: Could I be missing a header()?

Comment: I understand if your expertise does not extend this far so Thanks a lot pax for the effort and your time.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486889/popen-returns-output-after-delay This provides a lot of clarity into the matter and I think it is what I need. Thought you might want to see after all this.