# popen returns output after delay?

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

I am executing FFMPEG with `popen()` to get the result of the process. The main reason I am doing this is so I can stream constant output and build a progress bar.

The issue is that the process starts and I receive some initial information. The rest of the information does not appear until after the process is done however. So essentially, the rest of the output (output on the progress) which comes on intervals when the process is going is delayed right before the process and all comes at once after the process is done which is useless.

I need the output to constantly come so I can update a progress bar. If I change 2>&1 to 2> stderr.txt that text file receives output consistently but I would like to receive in php since many processes may be running. **Anyone have any ideas on solving this? It seems noone can figure this out...and it is driving me crazy! IF anyone helps me figure this out (and actually solve it), I will start a bounty and then accept their answer.**

```
$handle = popen ('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/cave.wmv -deinterlace -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -s 480x320 -f flv /home/g/Desktop/file.flv 2>&1', 'r');
if ($handle) {

    while(! feof ($handle)) {

echo $read = fgets ($handle);

ob_flush();
    flush();
    } 
    pclose ($handle);
}
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
    ffmpeg version git-N-30561-g6700aa8, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers built on Jun 5 2011 21:10:26 with gcc 4.5.2 configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab libavutil 51. 4. 0 / 51. 4. 0 libavcodec 53. 6. 1 / 53. 6. 1 libavformat 53. 2. 0 / 53. 2. 0 libavdevice 53. 1. 1 / 53. 1. 1 libavfilter 2. 13. 0 / 2. 13. 0 libswscale 0. 14. 1 / 0. 14. 1 libpostproc 51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0 Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001) Input #0, asf, from '/home/geoff/Desktop/cave.wmv': Metadata: WMFSDKVersion : 11.0.5721.5145 WMFSDKNeeded : 0.0.0.0000 IsVBR : 0 Duration: 00:01:37.93, bitrate: 263 kb/s Stream #0.0(eng): Video: vc1 (Advanced), yuv420p, 320x240, 256 kb/s, PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc [buffer @ 0xacae200] w:320 h:240 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param: [scale @ 0xacbc120] w:320 h:240 fmt:yuv420p -> w:480 h:320 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4 [libx264 @ 0xacbb7e0] Default settings detected, using medium profile [libx264 @ 0xacbb7e0] using SAR=1/1 [libx264 @ 0xacbb7e0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle Cache64 [libx264 @ 0xacbb7e0] profile High, level 2.1 [libx264 @ 0xacbb7e0] 264 - core 115 r1995 c1e60b9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=1 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00 Output #0, flv, to '/home/geoff/Desktop/file.flv': Metadata: WMFSDKVersion : 11.0.5721.5145 WMFSDKNeeded : 0.0.0.0000 IsVBR : 0 encoder : Lavf53.2.0 Stream #0.0(eng): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 480x320 [PAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc Stream mapping: Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help 

**THEN AFTER THE PROCESS IS COMPLETE OUTPUTS**

frame= 49 fps= 0 q=29.0 size= 17kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate= 593.9kbits/s frame= 58 fps= 52 q=29.0 size= 29kB time=00:00:00.53 bitrate= 448.9kbits/s frame= 71 fps= 44 q=29.0 size= 48kB time=00:00:00.96 bitrate= 405.7kbits/s frame= 85 fps= 39 q=29.0 size= 69kB time=00:00:01.43 bitrate= 393.2kbits/s frame= 104 fps= 38 q=29.0 size= 90kB time=00:00:02.06 bitrate= 358.3kbits/s frame= 117 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 104kB time=00:00:02.50 bitrate= 339.5kbits/s frame= 134 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 119kB time=00:00:03.06 bitrate= 317.6kbits/s frame= 153 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 137kB time=00:00:03.70 bitrate= 303.5kbits/s frame= 167 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 153kB time=00:00:04.17 bitrate= 300.1kbits/s frame= 185 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 173kB time=00:00:04.77 bitrate= 296.8kbits/s frame= 201 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 199kB time=00:00:05.30 bitrate= 306.8kbits/s frame= 218 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 222kB time=00:00:05.87 bitrate= 310.3kbits/s frame= 237 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 245kB time=00:00:06.50 bitrate= 309.1kbits/s frame= 254 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 267kB time=00:00:07.07 bitrate= 309.7kbits/s frame= 270 fps= 34 q=29.0 size= 285kB time=00:00:07.60 bitrate= 307.2kbits/s frame= 292 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 314kB time=00:00:08.34 bitrate= 308.5kbits/s frame= 316 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 334kB time=00:00:09.14 bitrate= 299.3kbits/s frame= 336 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 356kB time=00:00:09.80 bitrate= 297.0kbits/s frame= 356 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 381kB time=00:00:10.47 bitrate= 297.9kbits/s frame= 375 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 405kB time=00:00:11.11 bitrate= 298.5kbits/s frame= 391 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 431kB time=00:00:11.64 bitrate= 303.5kbits/s frame= 408 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 456kB time=00:00:12.21 bitrate= 305.8kbits/s frame= 424 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 479kB time=00:00:12.74 bitrate= 307.8kbits/s frame= 441 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 503kB time=00:00:13.31 bitrate= 309.3kbits/s frame= 462 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 526kB time=00:00:14.01 bitrate= 307.4kbits/s frame= 483 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 546kB time=00:00:14.71 bitrate= 304.2kbits/s frame= 501 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 583kB time=00:00:15.31 bitrate= 311.9kbits/s frame= 520 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 609kB time=00:00:15.95 bitrate= 312.7kbits/s frame= 541 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 636kB time=00:00:16.65 bitrate= 313.1kbits/s frame= 559 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 668kB time=00:00:17.25 bitrate= 317.3kbits/s frame= 574 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 698kB time=00:00:17.75 bitrate= 321.9kbits/s frame= 593 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 732kB time=00:00:18.38 bitrate= 326.1kbits/s frame= 611 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 760kB time=00:00:18.98 bitrate= 328.0kbits/s frame= 631 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 788kB time=00:00:19.65 bitrate= 328.5kbits/s frame= 651 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 817kB time=00:00:20.32 bitrate= 329.2kbits/s frame= 670 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 842kB time=00:00:20.95 bitrate= 329.0kbits/s frame= 689 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 868kB time=00:00:21.58 bitrate= 329.4kbits/s frame= 707 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 896kB time=00:00:22.18 bitrate= 330.8kbits/s frame= 723 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 924kB time=00:00:22.72 bitrate= 333.0kbits/s frame= 741 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 955kB time=00:00:23.32 bitrate= 335.4kbits/s frame= 761 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 999kB time=00:00:23.99 bitrate= 341.0kbits/s frame= 783 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1025kB time=00:00:24.72 bitrate= 339.8kbits/s frame= 802 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1047kB time=00:00:25.35 bitrate= 338.3kbits/s frame= 821 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1076kB time=00:00:25.99 bitrate= 339.3kbits/s frame= 841 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1104kB time=00:00:26.66 bitrate= 339.2kbits/s frame= 861 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1137kB time=00:00:27.32 bitrate= 340.7kbits/s frame= 881 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1164kB time=00:00:27.99 bitrate= 340.7kbits/s frame= 901 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1196kB time=00:00:28.66 bitrate= 341.9kbits/s frame= 919 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1223kB time=00:00:29.26 bitrate= 342.5kbits/s frame= 939 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1259kB time=00:00:29.93 bitrate= 344.7kbits/s frame= 954 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1301kB time=00:00:30.43 bitrate= 350.1kbits/s frame= 970 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1337kB time=00:00:30.96 bitrate= 353.7kbits/s frame= 988 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1373kB time=00:00:31.56 bitrate= 356.3kbits/s frame= 1005 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1418kB time=00:00:32.13 bitrate= 361.4kbits/s frame= 1023 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1448kB time=00:00:32.73 bitrate= 362.4kbits/s frame= 1040 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1483kB time=00:00:33.30 bitrate= 364.9kbits/s frame= 1058 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1519kB time=00:00:33.90 bitrate= 367.1kbits/s frame= 1074 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1546kB time=00:00:34.43 bitrate= 367.7kbits/s frame= 1091 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1573kB time=00:00:35.00 bitrate= 368.3kbits/s frame= 1111 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1593kB time=00:00:35.66 bitrate= 365.9kbits/s frame= 1126 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1612kB time=00:00:36.17 bitrate= 365.1kbits/s frame= 1140 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 1637kB time=00:00:36.63 bitrate= 366.1kbits/s frame= 1151 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1657kB time=00:00:37.00 bitrate= 366.9kbits/s frame= 1170 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1692kB time=00:00:37.63 bitrate= 368.3kbits/s frame= 1190 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1724kB time=00:00:38.30 bitrate= 368.6kbits/s frame= 1208 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1751kB time=00:00:38.90 bitrate= 368.6kbits/s frame= 1225 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1776kB time=00:00:39.47 bitrate= 368.6kbits/s frame= 1242 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1806kB time=00:00:40.04 bitrate= 369.4kbits/s frame= 1265 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1840kB time=00:00:40.80 bitrate= 369.4kbits/s frame= 1283 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1858kB time=00:00:41.40 bitrate= 367.5kbits/s frame= 1298 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1874kB time=00:00:41.90 bitrate= 366.3kbits/s frame= 1317 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1898kB time=00:00:42.54 bitrate= 365.5kbits/s frame= 1335 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1931kB time=00:00:43.14 bitrate= 366.7kbits/s frame= 1353 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1966kB time=00:00:43.74 bitrate= 368.2kbits/s frame= 1371 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 1996kB time=00:00:44.34 bitrate= 368.8kbits/s frame= 1391 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2029kB time=00:00:45.01 bitrate= 369.3kbits/s frame= 1410 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2062kB time=00:00:45.64 bitrate= 370.2kbits/s frame= 1430 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2089kB time=00:00:46.31 bitrate= 369.4kbits/s frame= 1449 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2114kB time=00:00:46.94 bitrate= 368.8kbits/s frame= 1469 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2140kB time=00:00:47.61 bitrate= 368.1kbits/s frame= 1488 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2169kB time=00:00:48.24 bitrate= 368.3kbits/s frame= 1506 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2212kB time=00:00:48.84 bitrate= 371.0kbits/s frame= 1522 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2248kB time=00:00:49.38 bitrate= 372.8kbits/s frame= 1540 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2278kB time=00:00:49.98 bitrate= 373.4kbits/s frame= 1558 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2314kB time=00:00:50.58 bitrate= 374.7kbits/s frame= 1577 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2346kB time=00:00:51.21 bitrate= 375.2kbits/s frame= 1598 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2377kB time=00:00:51.91 bitrate= 375.1kbits/s frame= 1615 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2409kB time=00:00:52.48 bitrate= 375.9kbits/s frame= 1633 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2440kB time=00:00:53.08 bitrate= 376.4kbits/s frame= 1651 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2470kB time=00:00:53.68 bitrate= 376.9kbits/s frame= 1670 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2501kB time=00:00:54.32 bitrate= 377.2kbits/s frame= 1690 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2539kB time=00:00:54.98 bitrate= 378.3kbits/s frame= 1707 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2570kB time=00:00:55.55 bitrate= 378.9kbits/s frame= 1725 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2601kB time=00:00:56.15 bitrate= 379.4kbits/s frame= 1743 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2632kB time=00:00:56.75 bitrate= 379.8kbits/s frame= 1762 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2677kB time=00:00:57.39 bitrate= 382.2kbits/s frame= 1781 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2706kB time=00:00:58.02 bitrate= 382.0kbits/s frame= 1800 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2738kB time=00:00:58.65 bitrate= 382.3kbits/s frame= 1821 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2765kB time=00:00:59.36 bitrate= 381.6kbits/s frame= 1841 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 2793kB time=00:01:00.02 bitrate= 381.2kbits/s frame= 1857 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2822kB time=00:01:00.56 bitrate= 381.7kbits/s frame= 1875 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2849kB time=00:01:01.16 bitrate= 381.6kbits/s frame= 1894 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2874kB time=00:01:01.79 bitrate= 381.0kbits/s frame= 1914 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2900kB time=00:01:02.46 bitrate= 380.4kbits/s frame= 1933 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 2924kB time=00:01:03.09 bitrate= 379.7kbits/s frame= 1954 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 2946kB time=00:01:03.79 bitrate= 378.3kbits/s frame= 1974 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 2971kB time=00:01:04.46 bitrate= 377.5kbits/s frame= 1991 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 3005kB time=00:01:05.03 bitrate= 378.5kbits/s frame= 2006 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3043kB time=00:01:05.53 bitrate= 380.4kbits/s frame= 2024 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3074kB time=00:01:06.13 bitrate= 380.8kbits/s frame= 2042 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3099kB time=00:01:06.73 bitrate= 380.5kbits/s frame= 2059 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3122kB time=00:01:07.30 bitrate= 380.0kbits/s frame= 2077 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3149kB time=00:01:07.90 bitrate= 379.9kbits/s frame= 2096 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3172kB time=00:01:08.53 bitrate= 379.2kbits/s frame= 2117 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3196kB time=00:01:09.23 bitrate= 378.2kbits/s frame= 2129 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3214kB time=00:01:09.63 bitrate= 378.0kbits/s frame= 2147 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3246kB time=00:01:10.23 bitrate= 378.6kbits/s frame= 2167 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3268kB time=00:01:10.90 bitrate= 377.5kbits/s frame= 2185 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3298kB time=00:01:11.50 bitrate= 377.8kbits/s frame= 2204 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3327kB time=00:01:12.13 bitrate= 377.8kbits/s frame= 2222 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3359kB time=00:01:12.74 bitrate= 378.3kbits/s frame= 2242 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3386kB time=00:01:13.40 bitrate= 377.9kbits/s frame= 2261 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3428kB time=00:01:14.04 bitrate= 379.3kbits/s frame= 2280 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3459kB time=00:01:14.67 bitrate= 379.5kbits/s frame= 2299 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3494kB time=00:01:15.30 bitrate= 380.1kbits/s frame= 2318 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3514kB time=00:01:15.94 bitrate= 379.1kbits/s frame= 2340 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 3539kB time=00:01:16.67 bitrate= 378.1kbits/s frame= 2360 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 3563kB time=00:01:17.34 bitrate= 377.4kbits/s frame= 2377 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 3586kB time=00:01:17.91 bitrate= 377.1kbits/s frame= 2393 fps= 36 q=29.0 size= 3606kB time=00:01:18.44 bitrate= 376.6kbits/s frame= 2410 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3625kB time=00:01:19.01 bitrate= 375.9kbits/s frame= 2427 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3639kB time=00:01:19.57 bitrate= 374.7kbits/s frame= 2444 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3656kB time=00:01:20.14 bitrate= 373.7kbits/s frame= 2461 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3680kB time=00:01:20.71 bitrate= 373.5kbits/s frame= 2473 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3702kB time=00:01:21.11 bitrate= 373.9kbits/s frame= 2488 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3722kB time=00:01:21.61 bitrate= 373.6kbits/s frame= 2506 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3764kB time=00:01:22.21 bitrate= 375.0kbits/s frame= 2522 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3788kB time=00:01:22.75 bitrate= 375.0kbits/s frame= 2539 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3820kB time=00:01:23.31 bitrate= 375.6kbits/s frame= 2556 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3851kB time=00:01:23.88 bitrate= 376.1kbits/s frame= 2571 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3885kB time=00:01:24.38 bitrate= 377.2kbits/s frame= 2587 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3919kB time=00:01:24.91 bitrate= 378.1kbits/s frame= 2600 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3949kB time=00:01:25.35 bitrate= 379.0kbits/s frame= 2616 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 3975kB time=00:01:25.88 bitrate= 379.1kbits/s frame= 2633 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4003kB time=00:01:26.45 bitrate= 379.3kbits/s frame= 2653 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4029kB time=00:01:27.12 bitrate= 378.9kbits/s frame= 2665 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4045kB time=00:01:27.52 bitrate= 378.6kbits/s frame= 2682 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4068kB time=00:01:28.08 bitrate= 378.3kbits/s frame= 2701 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4084kB time=00:01:28.72 bitrate= 377.1kbits/s frame= 2719 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4124kB time=00:01:29.32 bitrate= 378.2kbits/s frame= 2735 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4154kB time=00:01:29.85 bitrate= 378.7kbits/s frame= 2753 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4201kB time=00:01:30.45 bitrate= 380.5kbits/s frame= 2771 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4230kB time=00:01:31.05 bitrate= 380.6kbits/s frame= 2788 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4259kB time=00:01:31.62 bitrate= 380.8kbits/s frame= 2805 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4287kB time=00:01:32.19 bitrate= 380.9kbits/s frame= 2825 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4318kB time=00:01:32.86 bitrate= 380.9kbits/s frame= 2847 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4334kB time=00:01:33.59 bitrate= 379.3kbits/s frame= 2866 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4371kB time=00:01:34.22 bitrate= 380.0kbits/s frame= 2885 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4395kB time=00:01:34.86 bitrate= 379.6kbits/s frame= 2903 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4424kB time=00:01:35.46 bitrate= 379.6kbits/s frame= 2921 fps= 35 q=29.0 size= 4450kB time=00:01:36.06 bitrate= 379.5kbits/s frame= 2934 fps= 35 q=29.0 Lsize= 4512kB time=00:01:37.86 bitrate= 377.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=1 video:4454kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.293893% frame I:13 Avg QP:19.66 size: 13557 [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] frame P:1221 Avg QP:23.87 size: 2962 [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] frame B:1700 Avg QP:30.26 size: 451 [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] consecutive B-frames: 7.2% 33.5% 39.7% 19.6% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] mb I I16..4: 9.6% 73.3% 17.0% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] mb P I16..4: 0.4% 2.5% 0.4% P16..4: 37.8% 18.9% 8.1% 0.0% 0.0% skip:31.8% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] mb B I16..4: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0% B16..8: 30.9% 1.9% 0.4% direct: 0.9% skip:65.8% L0:30.8% L1:63.8% BI: 5.4% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] 8x8 transform intra:74.5% inter:72.0% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 79.7% 84.7% 50.5% inter: 14.2% 13.9% 0.7% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 60% 18% 4% 18% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 12% 10% 4% 10% 15% 7% 10% 7% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 19% 9% 4% 10% 13% 6% 8% 4% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 21% 22% 12% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.8% UV:0.4% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] ref P L0: 65.4% 20.8% 10.8% 2.9% 0.0% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] ref B L0: 91.4% 8.0% 0.6% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] ref B L1: 95.6% 4.4% [libx264 @ 0x95737e0] kb/s:372.66
```

Comment: Sorry for edit job, my browser won't let me format.

Comment: you need to specify ob_start at the head of your script, you cannot flush a closed buffer, first you need to open one!

Comment: Thanks Robert, but I still get the same behavior.

Comment: Even if I take all the flush out, and place an insert statement to insert $read, I get the same behavior. As if output just stops and then gets passed at end.

Comment: You guys are probably more advanced than me at this stuff, but don't php threads die at the end of the script? So you would need to start the job and let flash or jscript take over as the player. Right?

Again, I've never even attempted a streaming project, so I may have no idea what I'm talking about

Comment: Instead of using `fgets`, try `while (false !== ($char = fgetc($handle))) { echo $char; ob_flush(); flush(); }`

Comment: @meteorainer what does that have to do with my pain and suffering of trying to solve this?

Comment: @j.w.r. holy f*****g jeepers creepers, jwr, you may have just solved this. I need to test more but this could be it!!!!!!!

Comment: let me test some more before i get excited for no reason and look dumber than someone who just received a fake lottery ticket and tells his boss to...well you know.

Comment: ffmpeg using a carriage return `\r` instead of sending a new line `\n` each time it updates its status. This is why you are getting such a long line with `fgets`. The new line `\n` is not sent until its done.

Comment: @datasage How can I address that datasage? I think you are right.

Comment: Can ffmpeg be specified to output in lines?

Comment: Excellent comment by the way, really provided clarity.

Comment: @datasage: Humm... The docs for `stream_get_line()` say: **This function is nearly identical to fgets() except in that it allows end of line delimiters other than the standard \n, \r, and \r\n, and does not return the delimiter itself**. So, `fgets()` returns at `\r`s or not? Also, @Scarface: `stream_get_line()` seems to be able to save you the trouble of checking for carriage returns manually.

Comment: @Scarface: From the `fgets()` docs **If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the `auto_detect_line_endings` run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem**. If memory serves me right, Macintosh <= 8 use `\r` as line endings.

Comment: @Alix Excellent comments Alix! Thanks for contributing! I am not getting output so maybe I am using it wrong. I am doing while (false !== ($char = stream_get_line($handle,4096,'\n')))
{
echo $char;

Comment: @Scarface: Try `while (($line = stream_get_line($handle, 4096, "\r")) !== false)`, you need to use double-quotes for the delimiter - also, you want to check for `\r`, not `\n`.

Comment: Argh still no output. Now I am curious to try to use this function since it is quoted in the manual that it is much faster at reading. I am just using the while that you said and deleting `if ($char == "\r")
  {
    // You could now parse the $line for status information.
    echo "$line\n";
    $line = "";
  } else {
    $line .= $char;
  }` And then in the while statement I am echoing $line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code should collect a line of output then echo it, repeating until the program exits. (This worked for me, but only tested in Windows)

```
$handle = popen ('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/cave.wmv -deinterlace -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -s 480x320 -f flv /home/g/Desktop/file.flv 2>&1', 'r');
$line = "";

while (false !== ($char = fgetc($handle)))
{
  if ($char == "\r")
  {
    // You could now parse the $line for status information.
    echo "$line\n";
    $line = "";
  } else {
    $line .= $char;
  }
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
pclose ($handle);
```

Comment: I am working on developing your answer. Give me some time to test, but I think it is what I need. Thanks a lot for contributing. I will let you know when I finish. Once I confirm, I will place a bounty in a couple of days and accept if you want.

Comment: OK it works just how I want it. Thank you SOOOO much j.w.r. I will place a bounty and accept your answer in a couple of days!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that although the code in this answer works, it is far from optimal: it would be much faster to read blocks of data (say 256 chars at a time), splitting these blocks on newline chars and then gluing together any lines which get split across blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancier version of the answer from j.w.r which reads blocks of data instead of processing one character at a time (and bails out if ffmpeg produces no output for a whole minute).

On a linux system with PHP 5.2, I find that a loop of block data reads like this runs between 5 and 10 times faster than an equivalent loop over single characters:

```
$cmd = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/g/Desktop/cave.wmv -deinterlace -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -s 480x320 -f flv /home/g/Desktop/file.flv 2>&1';

$handle = popen($cmd, 'r');

$chunk_size = 256; // read up to 256 bytes of output at a time
$timeout_sec = 60; // time out after 60 seconds of no output

$line = '';

while (!feof($handle)) {
    $results = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);
    if (strlen($results) > 0) {
        $chunks = explode("\n", $results);
        while (count($chunks) > 1) {
            $c = array_shift($chunks);
            $line .= $c;

            // $line now has text up to a newline:
            echo "$line\n"; // could parse line for status
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            $line = '';
        }
        // last chunk of data block:
        $line .= array_shift($chunks);
    } else {
        sleep(1);
        $tc += 1;
    }
    if ($tc > $timeout_sec) {
        die("Timed out (after $tc seconds) waiting for output from [$cmd]");
    }
}
if (strlen($line) > 0) {
    // last line of output:
    echo "$line\n"; // could parse line for status
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

pclose ($handle);
```